# Caliburn.Micro ViewModel and ActivateItem - does not exist in the current context

Tags: viewmodel, caliburn.micro

The following code was working until I updated to the latest copy of Caliburn. Now I get an error on ActivateItem where it indicates it does not exist in the current context. Any suggestions?

```
using Caliburn.Micro;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace JCWPFUserInterface.ViewModels
{
    public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<object>
    {
        LoginViewModel _loginVM;
        public ShellViewModel(LoginViewModel LoginVM)
        {
            _loginVM = LoginVM;
            ActivateItem(_loginVM);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue. How exactly did you re-write the constructor?

Answer (score 5):

As far as I have read, `ActivateItem` no longer exists, maybe you can try `await ActivateItemAsync(/*...*/);` instead.

See https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/issues/697

Comment: My constructor is underlined red. What am I doing wrong? `private LoginViewModel _loginViewModel;` `public async Task ShellViewModel(LoginViewModel loginViewModel) { _loginViewModel = loginViewModel; await ActivateItemAsync(_loginViewModel); }`

Comment: @DinaM. if you hover over the underlined text, what error message is being displayed?

Comment: `ShellViewModel: member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type`

Comment: It's the constructor, so it has to have the same name as the class...

Comment: @DinaM. it seems to me that you try to create your constructor as an `async Task`. Can you test with your constructor not being an `async Task`?

Comment: I had to, because I thought the `ActivateItemAsync(_loginViewModel)` would require that. Wouldn't it? I changed it back to a regular method, but it does not work; i.e. the login view/form does not launch. Basically, `ActivateItem` is no longer available and should be changed to `ActivateItemAsync` and that does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: @DinaM. you could separate `await ActivateItemAsync(_loginViewModel);` into its own method and call it from the constructor.

Comment: Thank you, I did that and it works. Alternatively, I also tried reverting my `Caliburn Micro` back to the latest `3.x` version where `ActivateItem()` worked. Thanks for your help Lajos